# After upgrading python, Raspberry Pi boots to black screen with context menu only

Tags: screen, gui

I made the following changes (don't know how relevant they are)

1. Built Python 3.12 from source
2. `cp python3.12 /usr/bin/python`, (replacing `python2` with `python3.12` for when I call the `python` command)
3. I also tried to uninstall python3 following a guide that did not work (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68936574/update-a-raspberry-pi-to-python-3-9) includes `sudo apt-get purge python3.7`
4. I also installed xvfb `sudo apt-get install xvfb`

So now when I VNC into the pi, I get a black screen. I can click to open a context menu, where I see the following options:
[image: context menu]

Terminal Emulator and Web Browser both work. Hovering over Applications makes it crash. ObCOnf, Reconfigure both work as expected. Restart and Exit don't really do anything.

Any idea what I might've broken?

Comment: `Any idea what I might've broken?` - at a guess, Python - why did you feel the need to upgrade to a version of Pythin that isn't the so-called "standard"

Comment: Selenium mainly, it required a version of python higher than was installed

Comment: NOTE the link you followed is extremely poor practice; no responsible person would suggest this. It may have worked in the past when python2 was still supported but is almost guaranteed to crash a current OS.

Answer (score 1):

If you REALLY have a need for an unsupported python version install in a virtual environment.

You would be better employed installing an OS which natively supports an updated version (Bullseye has 3.9, Bookworm 3.11).